# angular $routeProvider does not parse django variables

Tags: python, django, angularjs

I have this route config:

```
    $routeProvider
        .when('/store', {
            templateUrl: '/static/js/partials/store.html',
            controller: 'StoreController'
        })
        .when('/groups', {
           templateUrl: '/static/js/partials/groups.html',
            controller: 'GroupsController'
        })
        .when('/groups/:id', {
            templateUrl: '/static/js/partials/group_page.html',
            controller: 'GroupPageController'
        })
        .when('/purchases', {
            templateUrl: '/static/js/partials/purchases.html',
            controller: 'PurchaseController'
        })
        .when('/settings', {
            templateUrl: '/static/js/partials/settings.html',
            controller: 'SettingsController'
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/static/js/partials//store'});
```

There are lots of django variables and other django stuff used in those HTML files.

But they are not being parsed. For example:

```
{% trans 'vouchers' %}
```

is shown in the view insted of 'vouchers'

Why is this happening? How to fix this?

Comment: Angular is client side rendering. Why should Django render them?
You should put the variables inside the js instead

Comment: @hyades ok, let me reprhase the question. What should I do so that those html pages will be considered as django templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django templating engine is done on the server side

Angularjs routeProvide is implemented fo[r client side routing.](http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/backend-integration-with-node-express/implementing-client-side-routing.html)

Hence, your django variables will not be parsed. (since all changes are done on client-side by angularjs and dont actually and is not interpreted by the django templating engine)